# Каким образом передать новый запрос?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Здравствуйте. Такая задача. Есть два поля для ввода (input). Оба они на одной странице. И в этих полях, при вводе текста, появляются подсказки с возможными вариантами(из базы данных).

Мне же нужно сделать, чтобы во втором поле, подсказки зависели от того что введено в первое поле. Например, в базе есть подсказки для первого поля: Машина, Дерево. А для второго поля, в базе занесены подсказки для обоих вариантов, для Машина: грузовик, легковой. Для Дерево: Сосна, Береза.

И вот если в первое поле поле пользователь написал Машина, то во втором поле должны быть подсказки только для машины.

Как делать выбору из базы я знаю. 
Я не знаю как без перезагрузки страницы сформулировать sql запрос, и тут же вывести его.

Я пытался сделать так:

```
$('#street').blur(function(e) {
var name_st = this.value;

$.ajax( {
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/inc/adres.php',
  data: {info:name_st},
  'success' : function (result) {
  }
});

});
```

Этим кодом я определил что введено в первое поле, и после выхода из этого поля, посылаю POST на php файл (adres.php), в котором должна идти выборка из базы, по введенному слову.

Файл adres.php я вывожу инклудом, в самом начале страницы.

Код файла:

```
if (isset($_POST['info'])){

$sql_streetj = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `street` WHERE `name_ru` = '".$_POST['info']."' "));

  $sl2 = array();
  $all_city_db2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `houses` WHERE `id_street` = '$sql_streetj[id]'");
  while ($city_name_ru2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_city_db2)) {
    $sl2[] = $city_name_ru2['name_ru'];
  }

}else{
    $sl2 = array();
    $all_city_db2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `houses`");
    while ($city_name_ru2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_city_db2)) {
      $sl2[] = $city_name_ru2['name_ru'];
    }
}
```

Логика этого файла: Если есть POST то должен сформулироваться массив с подсказками, для второго поля. Если POST нету, тогда формируется массив, и в нем все возможные подсказки, для всех вариантов, без выборки.

В итоге получается что при загрузке страницы формируется массив со всеми возможными подсказками(так как POST еще нет), а после того как заполняю первое поле, ничего не происходит, массив с подсказками остается прежний, как будто бы и не посылался POST.

Может быть я что-то упускаю? Может быть на странице php код не обновляется?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь. 
P.S. знания js у меня не очень.

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы отдать что то в `result` в js вам надо сформировать ответ и вывести в формате `json`, `html` либо другим каким либо спобом. Далее фаил не стоит инклудить а сделайте его отдельной страницей. И модифицируйте:

к примеру `фаил /inc/adres_json.php`

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

if (isset($_POST['info'])){
$sql_streetj = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `street` WHERE `name_ru` = '".$_POST['info']."' "));

  $sl2 = array();
  $all_city_db2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `houses` WHERE `id_street` = '$sql_streetj[id]'");
  while ($city_name_ru2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_city_db2)) {
    $sl2[] = $city_name_ru2['name_ru'];
  }
}else{
    $sl2 = array();
}

echo json_encode($sl2);
```

так вы в переменой result получите требуемый массив и уже на js сможите распарсить

```
$('#street').blur(function(e) {
var name_st = this.value;

$.ajax( {
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/inc/adres_json.php',
  data: {info:name_st},
  'success' : function (result) {
      console.log(result); // тут будет массив пришедший от php
  }
});

});
```

p.s. mysql - устарел используйте mysqli или pdo

p.p.s. Так же можно сгенерировать json со всеми подсказками и уже играться с этим масивом в js не запрашивая сервер лишний раз. т.е. Вы в вопросе придумали два подхода, один запрос на сервер ajax, другой обрабтока подсказок на js.

Comment: а для чего консоль.лог вызываем?

Comment: и как мне с этим массивом потом работать?

Comment: @Денис открываете консоль разроботчика и console.log туда выведет масив он для дебага что бы посмотреть что в массиве и придумать как работать с ним, ведь мы не знаем как эти подсказки вы собираетесь рендерить. Второй вопрос: это должны вы уже сами придумать, попробывать почитать и если вдруг возникнут сложности то спросить сдесь. А иначе ответ получиться очень громоздким.

Comment: так а массив с подсказками ( json_encode($sl2); ) я получу после заполнения первого поля?

Comment: по идеи да.....

Comment: просто для рендеринга подсказок мне нужен именно такой массив. и если это так то вообще здорово. немножко позже проверю все и дам знать.

Comment: в резалт вы получите именно такой массив который есть.

Comment: ничего не выходит. при загрузки страницы мы получаем пустой массив, так как нет POST . а после его отправки, массив не заполняется, как будто php не обновляется

Comment: @Денис разделили файлы?

Comment: нет, и зачем это? у меня же на одной странице эти поля для ввода, а в файл adres_json.php мы посылаем POST , и после этого должен вернутся заполненный массив. но он не приходит

Comment: что бы не путаться с header's раздели файлы один спецом для json другой для страницы

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете посмотреть в сторону [UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) + ajax

т.е после ввода текста в первом input - вы отправляете AJAX запрос с значением "Машина" и получаете данные из базы которые связанны с значением, после получения данных вы уже вводите в autocomplete (как? читать документацию)... и всё,  после когда пользователь начнёт писать во втором input-е уже будут показыватся подсказки для конкретного значения.
P.S объязательно почитать как работать с UI autocomplete (например [тут](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Comment: как делать autocomplete  я знаю, это я сделал. вопрос в другом, как делать выборку из базы после изменения текста в поле

Comment: т.е  основная проблема заключается в 
"а после того как заполняю первое поле, ничего не происходит, массив с подсказками остается прежний"
?

Comment: да. по идеи, после выхода из поля, должен идти POST с введенным словом, и по этому слову должна идти выборка из базы. все это я знаю как сделать. но вот почему-то заполненный массив, после выборки не приходит

Comment: вы файл adres.php инклудите(!?) в файл где должно получатся результат?

Comment: При ajax запросе ничего инклюдить не надо, вам же @Naumov общую логику написал. Почитайте как работать с Ajax  https://habrahabr.ru/post/14246/